# What is wrong with "delegate subtraction" if addition seems to be fine in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, resharper

I had a typo in my code and added a delegate where an `Event` should be used:

public Action AfterItemSelectionCallback;

The class that's using the supposed event contains:

```
this.folderListViewModel.AfterItemSelectionCallback += this.HandleItemSelection;
```

and later on removes the handler:

```
this.folderListViewModel.AfterItemSelectionCallback -= this.HandleItemSelection;
```

This builds and runs fine without errors or warnings.

Enter Jetbrains Resharper 8.1. I installed a trial of Resharper and it complains that

> "Delegate subtraction has unpredictable result."

- Why would += be okay if -= is not?
- Why does the compiler not complain if this is actually a problem?

Comment: I don't know why Resharper complains, but msdn tells me that `-=` **is** the way to *unsubscribe* an event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but I do _not_ have an event here.

Comment: Yeah, but events fundamentally *are* delegates that are invoked by the raising class.

Comment: The other question really seems to cover it, although it is dealing with events. Looks like Resharper is always issuing this warning. even for "real" events.

Comment: @MrPaulch I know but I may case I can change the code to `= null` instead of using `-=` and then Resharper is quiet. So my assumption was, it is throwing that warning only for delegates but it also does it for events.